# Using criteria API to compare only hour in ZoneDateTIme

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have entity class `Order` which has property `ZonedDateTime deliveryTime`. I'd like to extract all orders which delivery time was between e.g 11AM to 2PM for each day.

`builder.between(root.<ZonedDateTime>get("deliveryDate"), ??????, ????)`

I can limit my result to date boundaries but my goal is to limit delivery hours

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You might use [LocalTime#isAfter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isAfter-java.time.LocalTime-) and [LocalTime#isBefore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore-java.time.LocalTime-) for that:

```
ZonedDateTime now  = ZonedDateTime.now();
// 2017-04-18T14:54:38.567+01:00[Europe/Dublin]

DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ha");
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse("11AM",timeFormatter);
LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse("2PM",timeFormatter);

System.out.println(now.toLocalTime().isAfter(start)); // true
System.out.println(now.toLocalTime().isBefore(end)); // false
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: No need for a DateTimeFormatter.  Just use `LocalTime.of(11, 0)` and `LocalTime.of(14, 0)`.

Comment: but the problem is, I cannot invoke method `toLocalTime()` on my `root.<ZonedDateTime>get("deliveryDate")` because it's not instance of `ZonedDateTime.class` but interface Path and that is different kettle of fish